# A term for the phrases of exaltation following the utterance of a holy name (ie. god or prophet)

Tags: single-word-requests

In the Islamic tradition, whenever the name of God or the prophet Muhammad is uttered, the speaker often injects a short phrase of exaltation immediately after: for instance, the words [Subhanahu wa ta'ala](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subhanahu_wa_ta%27ala) may be spoken (or some other variation on the same theme).

Is there a technical or theological term for this practice?

I have tentatively settled on 'exaltation', as per the definition "the action of praising someone or something highly," but given the colloquial nature and everyday usage of these utterances, I suspect a more fitting word exists.

**Edit**: There is a Wikipedia article that addresses this topic specifically, referring to the phrases as [Islamic honorifics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_honorifics).

From the article: "Strictly speaking, it is incorrect to describe this or any of the following phrases as 'honorifics', since the latter are titles (as in the Persian form Hadrat-i Muhammad, where the honorific precedes the name). There seems to be no precise English word for the terms discussed here, but salawat could translate as 'blessings' or even 'prayers'."

Comment: Would you consider this the same as when you say, for example, “My dear husband—God rest his soul—always used to think that…”? Obviously, this comes after naming a non-deity, but the automaticness and the underlying sentiment of the excrescent phrase are much the same to me.

Comment: Good example, and, yes, the intent and usage is essentially the same. However, what I'm curious to know is whether there is a collective term for these profession-of-faith type sayings. Possibly, if memory serves, similar words are spoken (albeit more formally) in Catholic liturgy.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Is 'automaticness' a word? According to the ODE  'automaticity' is the acceptable noun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the Wikipedia article calls such phrases as “Peace be upon him” *Islamic honorifics,* it‘s correct in saying that they are not really honorifics at all. Honorifics generally precede the name in English.

There’s a Wikipedia article on [Peace be upon him](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peace_be_upon_him_(Islam)) specifically. That mentions that Arabic name *salawat* but also uses the words *supplication* and *greeting*.

A possible English word might be *blessing* or *benediction* — although it should be understood that the blessing being sought is God’s and not the speaker’s. It **may** be sufficient to call such a phrase an *acknowledgement.*

Because the practice of honouring a revered person in this way is entirely Islamic, ascribing an English name to it is never going to capture every nuance which the Arabic word holds. I suspect that *acknowledgement* won’t cut it, but the phrase certainly fits the English definition of a *benediction*.

> **1.2** a prayer asking for divine blessing.
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/benediction)

Answer (score -2):

Not sure, but I would use **by jove**, **Incha' Allah** or **Good heavens**!

Comment: Not quite. I will edit my original question with an excerpt that hopefully illustrates more clearly the usage I'm referring to. What I'm driving at, more specifically, is a possible term that refers to those phrases which follow the name of Allah or Muhammad in colloquial speech.

Comment: That is not what the OP is referring to :) An example would be: Mohammed, pbuh (praise be upon him), _whenever_ the name is used, spoken or written.

Comment: It would appear that as a new user I can't answer my own question, but I think I've found what I'm looking for. Answer in the edit to the original question.